# Side panel in Swift iPad

Tags: swift, ipad

I have issues with my side panel for iPad app. I need buttons stacked as below:

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Right now, my output produces:

Current Output:

[image: Current Output]

How can I remove circles and add button sets?

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


public protocol FrostedSidebarDelegate{

    func sidebar(sidebar: FrostedSidebar, willShowOnScreenAnimated animated: Bool)

    func sidebar(sidebar: FrostedSidebar, didShowOnScreenAnimated animated: Bool)

    func sidebar(sidebar: FrostedSidebar, willDismissFromScreenAnimated animated: Bool)

    func sidebar(sidebar: FrostedSidebar, didDismissFromScreenAnimated animated: Bool)

    func sidebar(sidebar: FrostedSidebar, didTapItemAtIndex index: Int)


    func sidebar(sidebar: FrostedSidebar, didEnable itemEnabled: Bool, itemAtIndex index: Int)
}


var sharedSidebar: FrostedSidebar?


public enum SidebarItemSelectionStyle{

    case None
    se Single

    case All
}


public class FrostedSidebar: UIViewController {


    public var width:                   CGFloat                     = 300.0
    /**
     If the sidebar should show from the right.
    */
    public var showFromRight:           Bool                        = false
    /**
     The speed at which the sidebar is presented/dismissed.
    */
    public var animationDuration:       CGFloat                     = 0.25
    /**
     The size of the sidebar items.
    */
    public var itemSize:                CGSize                      = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
    /**
     The background color of the sidebar items.
    */
    public var itemBackgroundColor:     UIColor                     = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.25)
    /**
     The width of the ring around selected sidebar items.
    */
    public var borderWidth:             CGFloat                     = 2
    /**
     The sidebar's delegate.
    */
    public var delegate:                FrostedSidebarDelegate?     = nil
    /**
     A dictionary that holds the actions for each item index.
    */
    public var actionForIndex:          [Int : ()->()]              = [:]
    /**
     The indexes that are selected and have rings around them.
    */
    public var selectedIndices:         NSMutableIndexSet           = NSMutableIndexSet()
    /**
     If the sidebar should be positioned beneath a navigation bar that is on screen.
    */
    public var adjustForNavigationBar:  Bool                        = false
    /**
     Returns whether or not the sidebar is currently being displayed
    */
    public var isCurrentlyOpen:         Bool                        = false
    /**
     The selection style for the sidebar.
    */
    public var selectionStyle:          SidebarItemSelectionStyle   = .None{
        didSet{
            if case .All = selectionStyle{
                selectedIndices = NSMutableIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: images.count))
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: Private Properties

    private var contentView:            UIScrollView                = UIScrollView()
    private var blurView:               UIVisualEffectView          = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark))
    private var dimView:                UIView                      = UIView()
    private var tapGesture:             UITapGestureRecognizer?     = nil
    private var images:                 [UIImage]                   = []
    private var borderColors:           [UIColor]?                  = nil
    private var itemViews:              [CalloutItem]               = []

    //MARK: Public Methods

    /**
     Returns an object initialized from data in a given unarchiver.
    */
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    /**
     Returns a sidebar initialized with the given data.

     - Parameter itemImages: The images that will be used for each item.
     - Parameter colors: The color of rings around each image.
     - Parameter selectionStyle: The selection style for the sidebar.

     - Precondition: `colors` is either `nil` or contains the same number of elements as `itemImages`.
    */
    public init(itemImages: [UIImage], colors: [UIColor]?, selectionStyle: SidebarItemSelectionStyle){
        contentView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        contentView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        contentView.bounces = true
        contentView.clipsToBounds = false
        contentView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        contentView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        if let colors = colors{
            assert(itemImages.count == colors.count, "If item color are supplied, the itemImages and colors arrays must be of the same size.")
        }

        self.selectionStyle = selectionStyle
        borderColors = colors
        images = itemImages

        for (index, image) in images.enumerate(){
            let view = CalloutItem(index: index)
            view.clipsToBounds = true
            view.imageView.image = image
            contentView.addSubview(view)
            itemViews += [view]
            if let borderColors = borderColors{
                if selectedIndices.containsIndex(index){
                    let color = borderColors[index]
                    view.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
                }
            } else{
                view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            }
        }

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }

    public override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        if isViewLoaded(){
            dismissAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    public override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        view.addSubview(dimView)
        view.addSubview(blurView)
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FrostedSidebar.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
    }

    /**
     Shows the sidebar in a view controller.

     - Parameter viewController: The view controller in which to show the sidebar.
     - Parameter animated: If the sidebar should be animated.
    */
    public func showInViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool){
        layoutItems()
        if let bar = sharedSidebar{
            bar.dismissAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }

        delegate?.sidebar(self, willShowOnScreenAnimated: animated)

        sharedSidebar = self

        addToParentViewController(viewController, callingAppearanceMethods: true)
        view.frame = viewController.view.bounds

        dimView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        dimView.alpha = 0
        dimView.frame = view.bounds

        let parentWidth = view.bounds.size.width
        var contentFrame = view.bounds
        contentFrame.origin.x = showFromRight ? parentWidth : -width
        contentFrame.size.width = width
        contentView.frame = contentFrame
        contentView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        layoutItems()

        var blurFrame = CGRect(x: showFromRight ? view.bounds.size.width : 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: view.bounds.size.height)
        blurView.frame = blurFrame
        blurView.contentMode = showFromRight ? UIViewContentMode.TopRight : UIViewContentMode.TopLeft
        blurView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.insertSubview(blurView, belowSubview: contentView)

        contentFrame.origin.x = showFromRight ? parentWidth - width : 0
        blurFrame.origin.x = contentFrame.origin.x
        blurFrame.size.width = width

        let animations: () -> () = {
            self.contentView.frame = contentFrame
            self.blurView.frame = blurFrame
            self.dimView.alpha = 0.25
        }
        let completion: (Bool) -> Void = { finished in
            if finished{
                self.delegate?.sidebar(self, didShowOnScreenAnimated: animated)
            }
        }

        if animated{
            UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(animationDuration), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: animations, completion: completion)
        } else{
            animations()
            completion(true)
        }

        for (index, item) in itemViews.enumerate(){
            item.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.3, 0.3, 1)
            item.alpha = 0
            item.originalBackgroundColor = itemBackgroundColor
            item.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            animateSpringWithView(item, idx: index, initDelay: animationDuration)
        }

         self.isCurrentlyOpen = true
    }

    /**
     Dismisses the sidebar.

     - Parameter animated: If the sidebar should be animated.
     - Parameter completion: Completion handler called when the sidebar is dismissed.
    */
    public func dismissAnimated(animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?){
        let completionBlock: (Bool) -> Void = {finished in
            self.removeFromParentViewControllerCallingAppearanceMethods(true)
            self.delegate?.sidebar(self, didDismissFromScreenAnimated: true)
            self.layoutItems()
            if let completion = completion{
                completion(finished)
            }
        }
        delegate?.sidebar(self, willDismissFromScreenAnimated: animated)
        if animated{
            let parentWidth = view.bounds.size.width
            var contentFrame = contentView.frame
            contentFrame.origin.x = showFromRight ? parentWidth : -width
            var blurFrame = blurView.frame
            blurFrame.origin.x = showFromRight ? parentWidth : 0
            blurFrame.size.width = 0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(animationDuration), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
                self.contentView.frame = contentFrame
                self.blurView.frame = blurFrame
                self.dimView.alpha = 0
                }, completion: completionBlock)
        } else{
            completionBlock(true)
        }

        self.isCurrentlyOpen = false
    }

    /**
     Selects the item at the given index.

     - Parameter index: The index of the item to select.
    */
    public func selectItemAtIndex(index: Int){
        let didEnable = !selectedIndices.containsIndex(index)
        if let borderColors = borderColors{
            let stroke = borderColors[index]
            let item = itemViews[index]
            if didEnable{
                if case .Single = selectionStyle{
                    selectedIndices.removeAllIndexes()
                    for item in itemViews{
                        item.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
                    }
                }
                item.layer.borderColor = stroke.CGColor

                let borderAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
                borderAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
                borderAnimation.toValue = stroke.CGColor
                borderAnimation.duration = 0.5
                item.layer.addAnimation(borderAnimation, forKey: nil)
                selectedIndices.addIndex(index)

            } else{
                if case .None = selectionStyle{
                        item.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
                        selectedIndices.removeIndex(index)
                }
            }
            let pathFrame = CGRect(x: -CGRectGetMidX(item.bounds), y: -CGRectGetMidY(item.bounds), width: item.bounds.size.width, height: item.bounds.size.height)
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: pathFrame, cornerRadius: item.layer.cornerRadius)
            let shapePosition = view.convertPoint(item.center, fromView: contentView)
            let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
            circleShape.path = path.CGPath
            circleShape.position = shapePosition
            circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            circleShape.opacity = 0
            circleShape.strokeColor = stroke.CGColor
            circleShape.lineWidth = borderWidth
            view.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)

            let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
            scaleAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
            scaleAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(2.5, 2.5, 1))
            let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
            alphaAnimation.toValue = 0
            let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
            animation.animations = [scaleAnimation, alphaAnimation]
            animation.duration = 0.5
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
            circleShape.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
        }
        if let action = actionForIndex[index]{
            action()
        }
        delegate?.sidebar(self, didTapItemAtIndex: index)
        delegate?.sidebar(self, didEnable: didEnable, itemAtIndex: index)
    }

    //MARK: Private Classes

    private class CalloutItem: UIView{
        var imageView:              UIImageView                 = UIImageView()
        var itemIndex:              Int
        var originalBackgroundColor:UIColor? {
            didSet{
                backgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor
            }
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            itemIndex = 0
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        init(index: Int){
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            itemIndex = index
            super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
            addSubview(imageView)
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            let inset: CGFloat = bounds.size.height/2
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inset, height: inset)
            imageView.center = CGPoint(x: inset, y: inset)
        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

            var r: CGFloat = 0, g: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
            let darkenFactor: CGFloat = 0.3
            var darkerColor: UIColor
            if originalBackgroundColor != nil && originalBackgroundColor!.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a){
                darkerColor = UIColor(red: max(r - darkenFactor, 0), green: max(g - darkenFactor, 0), blue: max(b - darkenFactor, 0), alpha: a)
            } else if originalBackgroundColor != nil && originalBackgroundColor!.getWhite(&r, alpha: &a){
                darkerColor = UIColor(white: max(r - darkenFactor, 0), alpha: a)
            } else{
                darkerColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                assert(false, "Item color should be RBG of White/Alpha in order to darken the button")
            }
            backgroundColor = darkerColor
        }

        override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
            backgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor
        }

        override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
            backgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor
        }

    }

    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func animateSpringWithView(view: CalloutItem, idx: Int, initDelay: CGFloat){
        let delay: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(initDelay) + NSTimeInterval(idx) * 0.1
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
            delay: delay,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 10.0,
            initialSpringVelocity: 50.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState,
            animations: {
                view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
                view.alpha = 1
            },
            completion: nil)
    }

    @objc private func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let location = recognizer.locationInView(view)
        if !CGRectContainsPoint(contentView.frame, location){
            dismissAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        } else{
            let tapIndex = indexOfTap(recognizer.locationInView(contentView))
            if let tapIndex = tapIndex{
                selectItemAtIndex(tapIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    private func layoutSubviews(){
        let x = showFromRight ? parentViewController!.view.bounds.size.width - width : 0
        contentView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: width, height: parentViewController!.view.bounds.size.height)
        blurView.frame = contentView.frame
        layoutItems()
    }

    private func layoutItems(){
        let leftPadding: CGFloat = (width - itemSize.width) / 2
        let topPadding: CGFloat = leftPadding
        for (index, item) in itemViews.enumerate(){
            let idx: CGFloat = adjustForNavigationBar ? CGFloat(index) + 0.5 : CGFloat(index)

            let frame = CGRect(x: leftPadding, y: topPadding*idx + itemSize.height*idx + topPadding, width:itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height)
            item.frame = frame
            item.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
            item.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            item.alpha = 0
            if selectedIndices.containsIndex(index){
                if let borderColors = borderColors{
                    item.layer.borderColor = borderColors[index].CGColor
                }
            }
        }
        let itemCount = CGFloat(itemViews.count)
        if adjustForNavigationBar{
            contentView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, (itemCount + 0.5) * (itemSize.height + topPadding) + topPadding)
        } else {
            contentView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, itemCount * (itemSize.height + topPadding) + topPadding)
        }
    }

    private func indexOfTap(location: CGPoint) -> Int? {
        var index: Int?
        for (idx, item) in itemViews.enumerate(){
            if CGRectContainsPoint(item.frame, location){
                index = idx
                break
            }
        }
        return index
    }

    private func addToParentViewController(viewController: UIViewController, callingAppearanceMethods: Bool){
        if let _ = parentViewController{
            removeFromParentViewControllerCallingAppearanceMethods(callingAppearanceMethods)
        }
        if callingAppearanceMethods{
            beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
        }
        viewController.addChildViewController(self)
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        if callingAppearanceMethods{
            endAppearanceTransition()
        }
    }

    private func removeFromParentViewControllerCallingAppearanceMethods(callAppearanceMethods: Bool){

        if callAppearanceMethods{
            beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: false)
        }
        willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParentViewController()
        if callAppearanceMethods{
            endAppearanceTransition()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please upload a sample project that reproduces your issue?  It's hard to create this scenario with only code and not the xib or Storyboard file.

Comment: It should be the matter of your library. See the library configurations if it allows you to create not cirlce buttons.
If there is no solution to disable circle buttons, then consider to use this library https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting each button in it's own view, you need to create a view that contains 3 buttons and then add the circle to the view.